# Select and copy the lines under a condition

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have the columns:

```
1   3   0.0133  0.2617  0.0084  311 0.4770  357     0.0068  0.0021  89
1   6   0.0133  0.2617  0.0084  311 0.4770  357     0.0185  0.0043  44
1   12  0.0133  0.2617  0.0084  311 0.4770  357     0.0277  0.0096  22
1   24  0.0133  0.2617  0.0084  311 0.4770  357     0.1131  0.0515  11
1   36  0.0133  0.2617  0.0084  311 0.4770  357     0.1376  0.1802  7
1   48  0.0133  0.2617  0.0084  311 0.4770  357     0.0335  0.0394  7
1   60  0.0133  0.2617  0.0084  311 0.4770  357     0.2515  0.1033  5
2   3   0.5207  0.0281  1.0802  275 0.1326  130     0.9377  1.4201  115
2   6   0.5207  0.0281  1.0802  275 0.1326  130     0.8975  1.2588  46
2   12  0.5207  0.0281  1.0802  275 0.1326  130     0.9535  1.0329  23
2   24  0.5207  0.0281  1.0802  275 0.1326  130     0.9225  1.2340  14
2   36  0.5207  0.0281  1.0802  275 0.1326  130     0.7426  1.0324  12
2   48  0.5207  0.0281  1.0802  275 0.1326  130     0.8580  1.2857  9
2   60  0.5207  0.0281  1.0802  275 0.1326  130     1.0000  1.3746  2
3   3   0.5378  0.2874  1.0023  224 0.5617  165     0.6589  1.2339  64
3   6   0.5378  0.2874  1.0023  224 0.5617  165     0.6387  0.9947  32
3   12  0.5378  0.2874  1.0023  224 0.5617  165     0.4644  0.6237  17
3   24  0.5378  0.2874  1.0023  224 0.5617  165     0.5526  1.1655  8
3   36  0.5378  0.2874  1.0023  224 0.5617  165     0.2831  0.9118  4
3   48  0.5378  0.2874  1.0023  224 0.5617  165     0.5362  0.7057  4
3   60  0.5378  0.2874  1.0023  224 0.5617  165     0.7071  1.1029  3
```

I need to select the lines under a condition based in the 2nd column. First I need to select and copy only the lines which have the number 3 in the 2nd column. After, I have to apply the same procedure to the lines which I have the number 6, and so on until the lines where I have the number 60.

I think I have to select using the `iloc` to select the lines based on a condition, but I don't have idea in how I can write the code.

This data is just a small fraction of the data amount.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Are you facing any issues with your current code?

Comment: `iloc` will let you select based on the row-number. for selecting based on a condition, `loc` will be more helpful. You should give an attempt (I suggest using `.loc` and if you remain stuck on an error or two, update your question with your attempted code and error, and someone will correct it for you

Comment: I don't know how I can write the code to select the lines based on a condition of the 2nd column (first selecting only the lines which contain the number 3 in the 2nd column, after the lines which contain the number 6 and so on untill 60). Do you have some idea, please?

Comment: Hi Bruce, welcome to stack overflow. Most people here think this works best if you give an attempt of your own code first. If you google "pandas conditionally select rows" that should help you get started if you're really stuck

Comment: Thank you all! I got using this:

Comment: foo = df.loc[df['column']==value]